# pgfplots: percentage in matrix plot

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, 3d, tikz-external, nodes-near-coords

I'm trying to draw a matrix plot with the shown values in percentage.

I already tried:
`nodes near coords = {\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}`
Unfortunately this didn't work out.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,
height=18cm,
compat=1.13,
colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(1); gray(1cm)=(0.5)},
xticklabels={LPIBG, ALL, HPIBG  },
xtick={0,...,2},
ytick=\empty
}
```

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,
nodes near coords = {\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
xlabel style={font=\footnotesize},
    ylabel style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    xticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
    yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
 colorbar,
colorbar style={ ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
yticklabels={0,20,40,60,80,100},
yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize}},
  point meta min=0,
    point meta max=100,
every node near coord/.append style={xshift=0pt,yshift=-7pt, black, font=\footnotesize},
]

\addplot[
matrix plot,
nodes near coords,
mesh/cols=3,
point meta=explicit]
table[meta=C]{
x y C
0 0 80
1 0 36
2 0 40
0 1 64
1 1 80
2 1 60
0 2 52
1 2 84
2 2 72
0 3 72
1 3 28
2 3 32
0 4 56
1 4 84
2 4 80
0 5 72
1 5 52
2 5 44
0 6 4
1 6 84
2 6 41
0 7 37
1 7 69
2 7 84
0 8 63
1 8 53
2 8 82
0 9 78
1 9 74
2 9 39
0 10 39
1 10 63
2 10 88
0 11 76
1 11 74
2 11 49
0 12 39
1 12 6
2 12 88
0 13 46
1 13 33
2 13 75
0 14 88
1 14 67
2 14 54
0 15 79
1 15 83
2 15 75
0 16 50
1 16 46
2 16 71
0 17 92
1 17 71
2 17 75
0 18 46
1 18 33
2 18 8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

enter code here

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not work in your MWE because you are overwriting it by also giving the option `nodes near coors` to the `\addplot` command. Remove the latter one (or specify format here), and it will print. I added a thinspace before the percentage sign, although it can also be recommended to load the `siunitx` package and let that format and typeset the values for you.

Anyway, here's the quickfixed version:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
  width=5cm,
  height=18cm,
  compat=1.13,
  colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(1); gray(1cm)=(0.5)},
  xticklabels={LPIBG, ALL, HPIBG},
  xtick={0,...,2},
  ytick=\empty
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  enlargelimits=false,
  xlabel style={font=\footnotesize},
  ylabel style={font=\footnotesize},
  legend style={font=\footnotesize},
  xticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
  yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
  colorbar,
  colorbar style={%
    ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    yticklabels={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\,\%},
    yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize}
  },
  point meta min=0,
  point meta max=100,
  nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\,\%},
  every node near coord/.append style={xshift=0pt,yshift=-7pt, black, font=\footnotesize},
]

\addplot[
matrix plot,
mesh/cols=3,
point meta=explicit]
table[meta=C]{
  x y C
  0 0 80
  1 0 36
  2 0 40
  0 1 64
  1 1 80
  2 1 60
  0 2 52
  1 2 84
  2 2 72
  0 3 72
  1 3 28
  2 3 32
  0 4 56
  1 4 84
  2 4 80
  0 5 72
  1 5 52
  2 5 44
  0 6 4
  1 6 84
  2 6 41
  0 7 37
  1 7 69
  2 7 84
  0 8 63
  1 8 53
  2 8 82
  0 9 78
  1 9 74
  2 9 39
  0 10 39
  1 10 63
  2 10 88
  0 11 76
  1 11 74
  2 11 49
  0 12 39
  1 12 6
  2 12 88
  0 13 46
  1 13 33
  2 13 75
  0 14 88
  1 14 67
  2 14 54
  0 15 79
  1 15 83
  2 15 75
  0 16 50
  1 16 46
  2 16 71
  0 17 92
  1 17 71
  2 17 75
  0 18 46
  1 18 33
  2 18 8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]