# Best practice of placing commonly used pgfplots settings in a separate file?

Tags: pgfplots, input, documentclass-writing

As years go by and make more and more figures I have started to accumulate code I reuse often, new commands, settings etc for pgfplots. After a while it start to get a bit cumbersome, so I'm looking for a way to outsource these to an external file. One option would be to just use `\input{mypgfsettings}`, I guess at the very beginning of the file, or make a new documentclass over `standalone` and use that. My question is whether there is some other option that might be possibly `pgfplots` specific I am missing, and are there any `pgfplots` specific pro-s and con-s of either approach?

Comment: I am not aware of some pgfplots specific options.