# How to conditionally specify the options for nodes near coords in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

Now I'm plotting some ybar figures using pgfplots. I want to show the values on the ybar. However, some values are too small and I don't want to show them. The following is an example

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar stacked,
            nodes near coords,
            % nodes near coords*={
            %     \ifnum \pgfplotspointmeta>0.1
            %         \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}
            %     \fi
            % },
            ]
            \addplot table {
                1 0.5
                2 0.8
                3 0.02
            };
            \addplot table {
                1 0.5
                2 0.2
                3 0.98
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the above code, the ybar contains two segments. The bottom bar at x=3 is very small, and I don't want to display it. I want to use conditional option for `nodes near coords` as commented in the above code (the values less than 0.1 should not display), but it failed. I want to know the reason and how can I realize what I want.

Comment: It would be a lot easier just to do it manually than try to automate it.  Note: missing (blank) data is not plotted.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for your comment. I thought it is a easy thing for automating it, but actually I didn't find the suitable method to modify the code for automation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an automated solution for your question.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % use this `compat` level or higher so the new default that `nodes near coords`
    % are placed in the middle of the bars instead of over the top is used
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        nodes near coords,
        % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        % we create a style for the `nodes near coords` which is dependent
        % on the value
        % (adapted from <http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141006/95441>)
        % (#1: the THRESHOLD after which we switch to a special display)
        nodes near coords greater equal only/.style={
            % define the style of the nodes with "small" values
            small value/.style={
                /tikz/coordinate,
            },
            every node near coord/.append style={
                check for small values/.code={
                    \begingroup
                    % this group is merely to switch to FPU locally.
                    % Might be unnecessary, but who knows.
                    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
                    \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmeta<#1}
                    \global\let\result=\pgfmathresult
                    \endgroup
                    %
                    % simplifies debugging:
                    %\show\result
                    %
                    \pgfmathfloatcreate{1}{1.0}{0}
                    \let\ONE=\pgfmathresult
                    \ifx\result\ONE
                        % AH: our condition 'y < #1' is met.
                        \pgfkeysalso{/pgfplots/small value}
                    \fi
                },
                check for small values,
            },
        },
        % assign a value to the new style which is the threshold at which
        % the `small value` style is used.
        nodes near coords greater equal only=0.2,
        % -----------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        \addplot table {
            1 0.5
            2 0.8
            3 0.02
        };
        \addplot table {
            1 0.5
            2 0.2
            3 0.98
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought it is a simple problem, but actually the answer is beyond my expection, it is a bit complicated for me.

Comment: I also don't understand everything in the answer myself, i.e. all the details in `check for small values/.code`. But that is not necessary. One only needs to know *what this does in total*. Then you can modify the parts around that to satisfy your needs. Here two more examples doing similar stuff with similar code. If you compare then I think you find out what does what and will also be able to adapt it to your next needs ;) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364729/95441 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349619/95441

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the documentation [(page 115, see example below)](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=115), you can use a function to decide what to print near the coordinates. I guess you could use that for your purpose.

In your case, you just need an `else` case, I think.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2]
    \addplot[scatter,mark=*,only marks,% we use 'point meta' as color data...
    point meta=\thisrow{color},
    % ... therefore, we can't use it as argument for nodes near coords ...
    nodes near coords*={
        \pgfmathapproxequalto{\myvalue}{0.25}
        % standard TeX:
        \ifpgfmathcomparison
          true%
        \else
          false%
        \fi
    },% ... which requires to define a visualization dependency:
    visualization depends on={\thisrow{myvalue} \as \myvalue},
    ] table{
        x   y   color   myvalue
        0.5    0.2  1   0.25
        0.2    0.1  2   1.5
        0.7    0.6  3   0.75
        0.35   0.4  4   0.125
        0.65   0.1  5   2
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]